# How to make a Frontend-Uploader with additional settings for every image?

Tags: javascript, php, html, file-upload

I want to create a form where the customer can upload images and add some settings like is it matt or glossy, which format, number and so on.

Problem:
I need this for multiple uploads. That means: It would be nice if the customer can make the settings just for one image but also for all uploads.

At the end the images and settings should be send to a photostudio in an email.

I hope there is any help.

Comment: Who upvoted this? You should be slapped! ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @JayBlanchard, that emoji though, xD. And no, I did not upvote.